# Java: Multithreaded Concurrency with BufferedReader/InputStream

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I have an async method that kicks off a new thread to do some behind the scenes processing every time the api endpoint is called.

I have a buffered reader that gets the inputStream from the process to grab a specific line and write it to a file on disk. However I think I am dealing with some concurrency issues, because some files are empty. Here is my sample code:

```
    @Async
    public void runTaskAsync(String jobIDString) {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String line;
        String summary = "";

        try {
            Process gradlewProcess = runtime.exec( SOME PROCESS );
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gradlewProcess.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line WE ARE LOOKING FOR) {
                    summary = line
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Write the summary to a txt file
            PrintWriter summaryWriter = new PrintWriter(FILE NAME);
            summaryWriter.println(summary);
            summaryWriter.close();

            //Create the tar file
            runtime.exec(TAR SOME FOLDER);

            runtime.exec(MOVE TAR FILE TO ANOTHER FOLDER);
        }
.
.
.
```

There are also cases where the TAR file doesn't get moved to the folder (when multiple threads running simultaneously). I'm assuming this is due to IO concurrency, but not sure the best way to go about this.

How do I grab a specific line from a process output and store it to a file in a multithreaded scenario such as this?

Comment: Files would be empty because the input stream doesn't contain any "line WE ARE LOOKING FOR". Obviously. --- *FYI:* You forgot to close the input stream.

Comment: You're createing the resources locally in the thread, so it's highly unlikely that it's threading problems you're dealing with. It rather looks like you're not waiting for the `Process` object to finish, probably stop reading before the app did its first output.

Comment: You can check this example where it uses completale future to create chain of tasks on a large file asynchronously.  https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/how-to-read-large-file-in-java.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

If `FILE NAME` is the same name for different threads, obviously that won't work and cannot be made to work. Furthermore, why in the blazes are you using exec of all things to `mv` a file??

The usual strategy is, at least when writing (concurrent reading of the same field by many threads is no big deal, possibly not the most efficient thing, but not an immediate source of outright bugs), is to write to a uniquely named file (just roll up a long temporary name with a random generator), and then rely on ATOMIC_MOVE to move a file atomically. This requires use of the `java.nio.file` API which lets you run `Files.move(from, to, StandardCopyOptions.ATOMIC_MOVE)` which will fail if the target already exists, and succeed only if it didn't, atomically (as in, if a great many threads are all attempting to do this with the same `to` all at the same time, exactly one will succeed, and all the others will fail, and the end result is as if only the one that succeeded ran.

Note that the disk is likely the bottleneck; trying to speed up a task by opening 20 threads, each of which opens a large file to search through it to find some specific line, is usually nearly 20 times slower vs. just having one thread that does this. multiple threads is most assuredly not voodoo magic for 'faster'. Usually it's both a lot buggier and a lot slower unless you're very careful.

Once you're positive you NEED multicore for speed reasons, then streamline it. ONE process should read through that file, and start creating self-contained 'packets' of jobs (generally, a single object that contains all pertinent information about the job. In this case, that one line you're looking for and perhaps other details), then this system hands the job off to a thread. This thread does the work based on this packet of work and is reliant on **nothing else**. It reads from no fields (or at least, none that are shared with other threads), it doesn't touch the disk at all. It just returns the calculated result back to the main organizing thread which ensures the result is saved appropriately. There should be only one organizing thread - a task that just touches disks is not going to go any faster, generally, if you try to parallelize it.

Something like fork/join would be great for such a design - or search the web for 'map reduce java' and I'm sure you'll find plenty of tutorials. Do keep in mind that in async/multicore world, there is an absolute avalanche of FUD and lies about how single threaded "doesn't scale" and how all code should be async. If it sounds a bit preachy, skip it, it'll be one of those proselytising loonies who has no idea what they're on about. Can be a bit hard to separate the wheat from the chaff, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! FILE NAME is actually unique for each thread, I should've made this more clear. My background process is actually a long running gradle process. The reason I made it asynchronous is so the client does not have to sit and wait until the process finishes. Thanks for the suggestion for ATOMIC_MOVE